# Nicedit works localhost but not Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, nicedit

I have troubles with nicEdit.

Framework is ruby 2.0.0 / rails 4.0.1

When in localhost, works but only if you upload the page twice.

But when deploy in Heroku, it does not work at all.

I followed [this example](http://rorguide.blogspot.mx/2011/03/wysiwyg-editor-for-rails3.html) up to the line.

I have a niEdit.js under ../vendor/assets/javascripts

Here is my full form:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'nicEdit' -%>

<%= simple_form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label "Elige un cromo" %><br />
<%= f.file_field :chrome %>
</div>

<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.association :user, label_method: :name, collection: User.where(name: current_user.name), :label => "Cociner@" %>
<%= f.association :category, :label => "Categoría", label_method: :plato_category, collection: Category.all %>
<%= f.input :plato %>
<%= f.input :minutos %>
<script type="text/javascript">
   bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>
<div class="well well-small">
  <p>Tejemaneje</p>
  <%= f.text_area :tejemaneje, :rows => 10, :style => 'width: 700px' %>
</div>

 </div>
  <p>
  </p>
<%= f.button :submit, "Receta", :class => "btn btn-success" %>

 <% end %>
```

What should I do different for it to work fully both on localhost and heroku? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL SOLUTION:

I moved nicEdit.js under /assets/javascript and the script is now running, but it does not matter if inside NicEdit.js this line is

iconsPath : '/assets/nicEditorIcons.gif' and the icons under /assets/images/nicEditorIcons.gif, they do not display. The same for /assets/nicEditorIcons.gif

I moved the icons under /assets/javascripts and change the line to

iconsPath : '.../nicEditorIcons.gif'

And I also tryed to put the icons under /assets/nicEditorIcons.gif with the icons ther. Nothing works.

Does Heroku have a special place for icons? Do I have to change the script call? Any help?